# 'ProfileManager' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I'm trying to make a custom user model with username an email fields both unique and required, and I'm doing this by te example from 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example
Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from utils.upload import get_upload_path

class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have a username.")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address.")
        user = self.model(
            username = self.username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(username, email, password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=30, verbose_name=u"username")
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255, verbose_name=u"e-mail address")
    # Profile information
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30, verbose_name=u"first name")
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30, verbose_name=u"last name")
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30, verbose_name=u"city")
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30, verbose_name=u"country")
    # Forum information
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_upload_path("avatars"), max_length=255)
    signature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u"signature")
    # Contact info
    icq = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=16, verbose_name=u"ICQ number")

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

And when I run `python manage.py syncdb` command for the first time, creating a new database, and create a superuser, I get this error:

```
'ProfileManager' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
    user = self.model(
        username = self.username,
```

The Manager does not have a username - you mean just

```
    user = self.model(
        username = username,
```

because you are passing it as a parameter. The full traceback would have made that obvious.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! And there wasn't any traceback, it was just one single error string in the terminal after I've entered the data to create a supersuer for a new database.